# Can't understand how work @login_required in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I looked at the source code for `@login_required` in Django and I can't understand one row:

```
lambda u: u.is_authenticated
```

I can't understand where `u` comes from.

Full code:

```
def login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):

actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
    lambda u: u.is_authenticated,
    login_url=login_url,
    redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
)
if function:
    return actual_decorator(function)
return actual_decorator
```

Comment: Do you know how `lambda` works? Is that your question?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's a function that can be defined in one line. Let's take yours as an example: `lambda u: u.is_authenticated`

They keyword `lambda` tells Python that you are defining an anonymous function. `u` is the function's argument. Anything after the colon (in this case, `u.is_authenticated`) is the return value. So lambda `u: u.is_authenticated` is the equivalent of:

```
def some_function(u):
    return u.is_authenticated
```

Lambda functions can have multiple arguments defined, separated by commas, and other things. Read about them here: [Lambda (Anonymous) Functions in Python](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function).

Comment: I think author can't understand, from where appear argument "u" in this lambda func